# Power Query - Compare values in 2 columns and if they are the same, replace value in 1 column with blank

Tags: powerquery

Using power query editor is there a way to generate M-Code using an IF statement that will (for each row) compare values in 2 columns.  If they are equal, I want to keep the value in one column and replace the value with blank in the other column,

In the screen shot below, I want name of Country to appear only in the Country Column.  If the values in the Address4 and Country columns are equal, I want to replace the value in the Address4 column with blank

I then want to repeat the process for Address 3; if the value in Country column equal the value in the Address3 column, then replace value in Address3 with blank.

I only want one instance of the Country name in the Country Column only.
Many Thanks in advance

[image]

I have tried adding a conditional column but not working.  Would appreciate any help

[image]

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, please toggle checkmark to accept solution for your question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, edited manually in home..advanced editor...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
 Replace = Table.ReplaceValue(Source, each [Address4], each if [Address4] = [Country] then null else [Address4] , Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"Address4"}),
 Replace2 = Table.ReplaceValue(Replace, each [Address3], each if [Address3] = [Country] then null else [Address3] , Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"Address3"})
in Replace2
```

[image]